# React MUI Snackbar renders outside div

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, css-position, snackbar

Currently building a React front-end relying heavily in MUI elements. In my current design, I have two grids one next to each other, as shown in the code below.

```
<Grid item xs={6} sx={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'flex-end', margin: '30px', padding: '30px'}}>

                <Snackbar
                  open={openSuccessOperationInfo} 
                  onClose={() => handleSnackbarClose()}
                  autoHideDuration={6000} 
                  sx={{
                    width: '100%',
                    position: 'relative'
                  }}
                  >
                  <Alert onClose={() => handleSnackbarClose()} 
                        severity="success" 
                        variant="filled" 
                        sx={{ 
                          width: "100%" 
                        }}>
                        Installation Success
                  </Alert>
                </Snackbar>

                <Snackbar
                  open={openFailedOperationInfo} 
                  onClose={() => handleSnackbarClose()}
                  autoHideDuration={6000} 
                  sx={{
                    width: '100%',
                    position: 'relative',
                  }}
                  >
                  <Alert onClose={() => handleSnackbarClose()} 
                        severity="error" 
                        variant="filled" 
                        sx={{
                          width: '100%',
                        }}
                        >
                        Installation Failure
                  </Alert>
                </Snackbar> 

              </Grid>
```

When I render the snackbar, the size of the install button gets recomputed because the snackbar is not fit inside the grid where it is intended to. Any idea of why this is happening? Not a React, much less MUI expert myself.

This is how the Button on the Grid next to the Snackbar Grid renders, perfectly in place.
[image]

This is how the Snackbar renders, outside the designated space, which is what is causing in turn the size of Button to recompute.
[image]

NOTE: -> The issue is not the resizing of the Button but rather the fact that the Snackbar shows outside the designated space (where I actually intend to fit it), and therefore, both elements do not appear aligned but rather one shifted with respect to the other.

[image]
[image]

Much help appreciated.

Tried adjusting all possible combinations of the `sx` and `style` parameters in the `Snackbar` elements without any luck